# Import from MySQL to ArangoDB consistently incomplete (own Node.js script)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest, arangodb

I wrote a naive Node.js script to migrate a MySQL table to an [ArangoDB](http://arangodb.org/) collection.

It works quite well, despite that there are **always records missing** as if the connection was closed too early. How many documents will be missing is not random however, it's **always the same amount**:

- There are 68,750 records in the source,
- my self-built buffer has a size of 1,000 and
- 68,682 (-68) documents are created in ArangoDB

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var arango = require('arango');

var docs = [];

function processRow(row, connection) {
    if (docs.length < 1000 && row !== false) {
        docs.push(row);
    } else {
        connection.pause();
        db.import.importJSONData(
            "target_collection",
            JSON.stringify(docs, function(key, value) {
                if (value == null || (typeof value === "string" && !value.trim())) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            }),
            {
                createCollection: true,
                waitForSync: false
            },
            function(err, ret) {
                docs = [];
                connection.resume();
                if (row === false) process.exit();
            }
        );
    }
}

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: ''
});

var db = arango.Connection("http://localhost:8529/my_database");
connection.connect();

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM my_database.source_table');
var i = 0;

query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('result', function(row) {
        i++;
        if (i % 1000 == 0) console.log(i);

        processRow(row, connection);

    })
    .on('end', function() {
        processRow(false, connection);
    });
```

[Another version of the script](https://github.com/CoDEmanX/arango-import/blob/master/stream_array_join.js) I wrote uses a transform stream and imports exactly 68,744 records, and [a third script](https://github.com/CoDEmanX/arango-import/blob/master/stream_str_concat.js) all of the records but creates the target collection and records as it finishes, although it should write every *n* source records.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

A counter variable can confirm that all 68,750 records are read and there are no source records which are completely empty (all columns `NULL`), as there's at least a primary key integer (and I also tried without customized JSON stringify handler).

**Solution:**

Do something with every *nth* row when buffer is full, credits go to mscdex and mchacki for finding this obvious mistake!

Fixed [stream_array_join.js](https://github.com/CoDEmanX/arango-import/blob/master/stream_array_join.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight error in your process row function.
You trigger it with one row at a step and pushing all rows into the docs array.
When executing it for the 1000 row the docs are written into ArangoDB and you insert the next row.
And here is the error, the 1000th row is not stored in docs at any point.
One possible fix:

```
        db.import.importJSONData(
        "target_collection",
        JSON.stringify(docs, function(key, value) {
            if (value == null || (typeof value === "string" && !value.trim())) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }),
        {
            createCollection: true,
            waitForSync: false
        },
        function(err, ret) {
            docs = [row]; // Insert row here
            connection.resume();
            if (row === false) process.exit();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

In `processRow()` you're not doing anything with `row` in your else branch when `row` is not `false`.

So you might need to change:

```
function(err, ret) {
  docs = [];
  connection.resume();
  if (row === false) process.exit();
}
```

to something like:

```
function(err, ret) {
  if (row)
    docs = [row];
  else
    docs = [];
  connection.resume();
  if (row === false) process.exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was obvious and hard to spot at the same time!